# Creating a button to make user an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I am doing Hartl's tutorial and I want to make other users admins. Can I create a button that links to a action that updates the user's attributes to make them an admin?

```
<%= button_to "Make Admin", {action: "make_admin" }, method: :put %>

Users controller

def make_admin
   update_attribute(:admin, true)
   redirect_to users_url
end

routes.rb

put 'admin' => 'users#make_admin'
```

Had trouble referencing the right user. Any suggestions or a sure-fire way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route is missing an `:id`. Change it to

```
put 'admin/:id' => 'users#make_admin', :as => "make_admin"
```

Also, for `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "Make Admin", {action: "make_admin", id: current_user.id }, method: :put %>
```

and `UsersController`:

```
def make_admin
  user = User.find params[:id]
  user.update( :admin => true )
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

Comment: Getting this error: No route matches {:action=>"make_admin", :controller=>"users"}

Comment: how did you know it was an :id in my route I was missing that was the problem? Because you need an id to edit a user? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Exactly, if you want to do something with an object in some action, you have to pass some handler to identify it (`:id` in this case). ps. If you like my answer, you can accept it.